# Existing class from library implements interface

Tags: c++, opencv

I am developing a software which needs to detect different kinds of tracking codes (barcode, qr-code, RFID, etc). I have made an interface `TrackingIdentifier` which will be implemented by `BarcodeIdentifier`, `QRCodeIdentifier`, `RFIDIdentifier`, etc. For barcode and qrcode, the input to the detection algorithm will be cv::Mat &image. But for RFID it will be something else. The code will be something like this :

```
class TrackingIdentifier{

public:
virtual std::string getTrackingCode(ITrackingInfoHolder *holder) = 0;
};
```

Can the existing `cv::Mat` implement this `ITrackingInfoHolder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

```
struct MatInfo : ITrackingInfoHolder {
    info getInfo() override {
        return mat....();  // delegate to cv::Mat implementation
    }

private:
    cv::Mat mat;
};
```